# When having nodes of different sizes, edges with arrows enabled are not guaranteed to connect with nodes. How to fix that?

Tags: networkx

`nx.draw_networkx_edges` allows for only single value of `node_size` . The issue with that is that my nodes have different sizes. It means that if I'll set the edge's `node_size` to the "target" node's size, it will be mismatched with the "source" node's size. If the "target" is larger than the source, the edge will not be connected with the source node because it'll assume that it's bigger than it is. Is there any way to have an arrow connected with the border of both nodes if these nodes are of different sizes?

See:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - use an array as your `node_size` argument for [`nx.draw_networkx_edges`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html#draw-networkx-edges) rather than a scalar. Contrary to your question, the function does accept multiple values:

> `node_size` : ***scalar or array (default=300)***
> Size of nodes. Though the nodes
> are not drawn with this function, the node size is used in determining
> edge positioning.

The order of the nodes in the `node_size` array are given by the optional parameter `nodelist`. If this is not specified, the default is `G.nodes()`.